# How to use R to find the smallest positive solution to cos(x + b) = a

Tags: r

I need to write R code that reliably finds the smallest positive solution to the equation cos(x + b) = a. The variables a and b can take arbitrary values.

On the range [0, 2 \pi] the equation has two solutions provided abs(a) < 1. But if I try to solve this equation using `acos` I get just one answer and that may not be the smallest positive solution. As the graph illustrates.
[image: Graph of cos(x + b) showing intersection with y = a and with result of using acos]

What do I need to do to get the smallest positive solution?

Comment: Solutions to x in cos(x+b)=a are given by ±arccos(a) - b + 2*Pi*k, for integer k. So, in this case your desired solution is -acos(a) - b=1.952802. Probably it's possible to narrow down the range of possible values of k using the value of b, but I'm not sure now what it would be. In case you know that b is restricted to some interval, you could just consider ±arccos(a) and several values of k, and look for the smallest positive solution among all those.

Comment: In general I do not know what value b might take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to obtain the exact solution without optimization. As I said in the comment above, solutions x in cos(x + b) = a are given by ±arccos(a) - b + 2πk, for integer k. Hence, we want to compare two particular solutions that belong to the interval [0,2π]

1. x<sub>1</sub> = arccos(a) - b + 2πk with the smallest integer k such that arccos(a) - b + 2πk >= 0 and
2. x<sub>2</sub> = -arccos(a) - b + 2πk with the smallest integer k such that -arccos(a) - b + 2πk >= 0.

Given such x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> they both will be nonnegative and we want to pick min{x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>}. After some algebra we arrive to

```
a <- 0.5
b <- -3
k <- ceiling((c(-1, 1) * acos(a) + b) / (2 * pi))
min(c(1, -1) * acos(a) - b + 2 * pi * k)
# [1] 1.952802
```

It works for any a∈[-1,1] and any b.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Using uniroot.all, I time a single calculation at 0.061 sec; using @JuliusVainora's code, the time drops to 0.003 sec. In my application this calculation is performed in every iteration of a Monte Carlo simulation that time saving is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered the function `uniroot.all` in the package `rootSolve`. It solves my problem completely (at the cost of adding yet another package to my code.

```
fun2 <- function(x)
   cos(x + b) - a
 x <- min(rootSolve::uniroot.all(
   f = fun2,
   lower = 0,
   upper = 2 * pi
 ))
```

It might be that the use of `min` is unnecessary if `uniroot.all` invariably yields the roots in order of magnitude, but I cannot be sure that it does.

Comment: can you edit this answer to include a full solution? That way if someone wants to do what you're doing in the future, they can follow your guide! Best, ~Marian

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This finds the maximum of the curve between 0 and 2*pi. Then it finds the root between the interval 0 and the maximum.

```
a <- 0.5
b <- -3

max_op <- optimize(function(x) cos(x+b), interval = c(0, 2*pi), maximum = TRUE)$maximum
uniroot(function(x) cos(x+b) - a, interval = c(0,max_op))
```

**Original:**

Here is a potential solution. `optim` seems to return the right answer but throws a warning. `uniroot` and `optimize` work but takes some oversight as you have to provide a narrow interval.

```
optim(par = 1, fn = function(x) abs(cos(x+b) - a))
uniroot(function(x) cos(x+b) - a, interval = c(1,2))
optimize(function(x) abs(cos(x+b) - a), interval = c(0,2))
```

Comment: That is correct. Because in my application the variables a and b can take any value it is not possible to give a narrow range.

Comment: See edit that should work for any b. I assume that @Julius Vainora's comment could be used to skip some of the brute force of ```optimize```, but I don't know trig anymore.